# define NDK_ROOT in cocos2DX mutiplatform game environment

Tags: android-ndk, cocos2d-android

I have just started working with cocos2dx android and I am following wonderful tutorial of http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started . Now, I have successfully run my first hello world demo project by following this link. I also set environment parameters:

```
NDK_ROOT_LOCAL="/MY ANDROID NDK PATH/"

ANDROID_SDK_ROOT_LOCAL="/MY ANDROID SDK PATH/"
```

I followed tutorial perfectly as given in it, still I am facing problem while running my project second time, means I have to export DNK_ROOT every time from terminal to run my project & it's really tired and seemed not working for my further implementation..  and while I run project it says please define NDK_ROOT though I already define

## second thing

I also manually define these variables in my .bash profile (create-android-project.sh) this way

```
NDK_ROOT_LOCAL = "/MY ANDROID NDK PATH/"

ANDROID_SDK_ROOT_LOCAL = "/MY ANDROID SDK PATH/"
```

What am I missing in setting up this?

Answer (score 2):

To make those variables permanent (so every terminal shell you open hereafter has then) use your favorite text editor to update your bash profile (I chose vi to keep it in the terminal)

NOTE: the use of "~" in a path is just shorthand for **your** user directory. In your case it appears to be synonymous with saying *"~" = "/Users/alex"*

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

add the following lines and save (update these names and paths to *match* **your** actual environment, I am assuming everything is in the root of your user directory here):

```
export NDK_ROOT_LOCAL=~/android-ndk-r10b
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT_LOCAL=~/sdk
```

Use [source](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html) to run the profile in the current terminal session or just open a new terminal

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

You can test to see if the variables are defined here (use whatever you named them)

```
echo $NDK_ROOT_LOCAL

echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT_LOCAL
```

[EDIT: noted that paths need to be tuned to your environment]

Answer (score 0):

this way i can define my NDK ROOT

export NDK_ROOT=/Users/alex/android-ndk-r8b

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MAC OSX please consider adding NDK_ROOT variable in Environments file. Linux directly read it when the instance of bash is initiated but in MAC you need to add it in a bit more detail. Try adding it.

Comment: You mean to say .. i should define it in my .bash file  . Right ??