# NDK_ROOT not defined. Please define NDK_ROOT in your environment

Tags: android, python, eclipse, android-ndk

I have a problem regarding to cocos2dx v3 setting up android on mac. I use this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2LI1IrRp_0w) as a guide. In the video everything is doing fine but on my own eclipse, there's an error that shows up under my console tab. This is the statement error that I found : "python /Users/kirbyasterabadilla/Desktop/OracleEye/proj.android/build_native.py -b release all 
NDK_ROOT not defined. Please define NDK_ROOT in your environment".

I also tried installing NDK plugin inside my eclipse IDE but still can't solve the problem.

Please help me with this one. What should I do to make this error disappear?

Comment: Define your NDK_ROOT in your enviroment,see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676796/define-ndk-root-in-cocos2dx-mutiplatform-game-enviroment

Answer (score 2):

> python /Users/kirbyasterabadilla/Desktop/OracleEye/proj.android/build_native.py -b release all NDK_ROOT not defined. Please define NDK_ROOT in your environment

It sounds like you should export `NDK_ROOT` from you log in script. Below is from my OS X 10.8.5 machine:

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2012-07-19 at 20:21:05
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH

# Android
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/opt/android-ndk-r9
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/opt/android-sdk

export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
export ANDROID_HOME="~/.android"
export NDK_ROOT="$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT"

export PATH="$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/":"$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools/":"$PATH"
```

According to David Turner on the NDK Mailing List, both `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` need to be set because other tools depend on those values (see [Recommended NDK Directory?](http://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/qZjhOaynHXc/2ux2ZZdxy2MJ)).

Interestingly, Turner said nothing about `ANDROID_HOME` or `NDK_ROOT` (and searching the NDK group for `ANDROID_HOME` returned 0 results).

After modifying `~/.bash_profile`, then perform the following (or logoff and back on):

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

---

If modifying your log in script does not help, then try setting it in Eclipse:

[image]

See [Setting environment variables](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_run_env.htm).