# NDK_ROOT undefined. Please define

Tags: android-ndk, ndk-build

I am trying to compile these library into my android code https://sdk.dronecode.org/en/contributing/build.html . This library has C/C++ written code. Therefore NDK will be used here.

When I try to hit the command `sudo make android install` I get this error:

> Makefile:152: *** NDK_ROOT is undefined, please point the environment variable to android-ndk root..  Stop.

I have set the environment variable into my .bashrc file . But still getting this error, please help me out to get this compiled. I am using ubuntu 16.04. I have checked the other links "[NDK_ROOT not defined. Please define NDK_ROOT in your environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986085/ndk-root-not-defined-please-define-ndk-root-in-your-environment)" but couldn't helped much.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` does not source `.bashrc`

You can try directly running the command with your env explicitly defined

i.e. `sudo NDK_ROOT=xxxxx make android install`

or follow the advices [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228314/sudo-command-doesnt-source-root-bashrc), using `.profile`